# If every linear form $f: E \to \mathbb R$ that vanishes on $F \subset E$ is zero, then $E = F$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am workin in Galdi's *Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of the Navier-Stokes Equations* and somewhere in a proof we want to show that, for $E$ a Banach space and $F$ a closed subspace of $E$, $F = E$. To this end, he use the fact that if every linear functional $f \in E'$ that vanishes on $F$ is zero, then $F = E$.

I can add the definitions of $E$ and $F$ if it is needed but he presents this fact as a quite general result. I tried to find a proof in the literature but I couldn't find it anywhere. Does anyone have any idea where I could get the proof or how to show it?

Comment: Do you know Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Comment: This is a corollary to the Hahn-Banach Theorem (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn–Banach_theorem).

Comment: Ok I see how to show it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct application of the Hahn-Banach Theorem. Suppose that $F\subsetneq E$. Take $e\in E\setminus F$. Since $F$ is a subspace, it is linearly independent from $e$. So you can define, on $\operatorname{span}\{F\cup\{e\}\}$,
$$
f(\lambda e+\sum_jc_j g_j)=\lambda,\ \ g_1,\ldots,g_n\in F. 
$$
We need to show that $f$ is bounded:
\begin{align}
\|f\|&=\sup\big\{\tfrac{|f(\lambda e+ g)|}{\|\lambda e + g\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C,\ g\in F\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\big\{\tfrac{|f( e- g)|}{\|\lambda e - g\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C,\ g\in F\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\big\{\tfrac{1}{\|\lambda e - g\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C,\ g\in F\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{\inf\big\{{\|\lambda e - g\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C,\ g\in F\}}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{\operatorname{dist}(e,F)}.
\end{align}
The fact that $F$ is closed guarantees that $\operatorname{dist}(e,F)>0$, so $f$ is bounded. Now Hahn-Banach gives you an extension $f$ to all $E$, bounded, with $f(e)=1$ and $f|_F=0$.